Proxy_pass and Authorization Basic and Bearer
I have nginx as a reverse proxy. The proxy require authentication with Authorization Basic.
I can access the proxied server fine, until it gets to the request /api/config/config_entries/flow.
The API require an Authorization Bearer header, which is sent by the browser. The problem is that the proxy refuse the request because it doesn't have the Authorization Basic anymore.
How can I make nginx pass the Bearer token and ignore it itself ?
Nginx show those logs :
2024/11/24 20:08:46 [info] 55109#100183: *26059 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: myserver.com, request: "POST /api/config/config_entries/flow HTTP/1.1", host: "myserver.com", referrer: "https://myserver.com/config/integrations/dashboard"
2024/11/24 20:08:46 [info] 55109#100183: *26059 delaying unauthorized request, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: myserver.com, request: "POST /api/config/config_entries/flow HTTP/1.1", host: "myserver.com", referrer: "https://myserver.com/config/integrations/dashboard"
2024/11/24 20:11:50 [info] 55109#100183: *26086 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: 0.0.0.0:443

My nginx.conf is:
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name myserver.com;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
ssl_certificate /path/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/privkey.pem;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers CDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

auth_basic "Nope";
auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
auth_delay 5s;

location / {
proxy_pass http://proxied_server/;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
}


How can I make nginx pass the Bearer token and ignore it itself? – You can't. Even if you manage to construct an HTTP request with two Authorization headers, nginx will respond with a "400 Bad Request" error. However, if you can validate the Bearer token through your web application using a custom route, or if it's acceptable to bypass Basic authentication when a Bearer token is included in the request (perhaps only for API calls via a separate location), you might consider adapting this answer. If you need additional help, feel free to ask.
